# Oracle View inside an SQL Server Instance?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, view

I have an Oracle View (in an Oracle database). I am moving to a new project that uses SQL Server but this view contains data that I need access to.

Is there a way (other than dumping data then copying it to SQL Server)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between Linked Server solution and SSIS solution?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5712/whats-the-difference-between-linked-server-solution-and-ssis-solution)

Comment: you don't need ask any question. Pleas, first search in other question and answers. if their not complete please ask by referenced and write your tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a linked server in SQL that access the Oracle view, but be aware that this usually causes bad performance.

See: [https://www.sqlshack.com/link-sql-server-oracle-database/#:~:text=Using%20SSMS&text=To%20do%20so%2C%20connect%20to,name%20used%20in%20the%20tnsnames](https://www.sqlshack.com/link-sql-server-oracle-database/#:%7E:text=Using%20SSMS&text=To%20do%20so%2C%20connect%20to,name%20used%20in%20the%20tnsnames).

Comment: how would I do that? create a linked server?

Comment: I'll add a link to my answer